# PHP multiple forms with multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have several forms on a page called dispatch.php that each submit PHP code to INSERT into a database table and also UPDATE another database table. The main value that is INSERTED and UPDATED is the bolNum and containerNum.

Note:  There can be more than 1 bolNum or containerNum at any time. You'll see the array and how I broke it down.

Here is 1 form (I shortened this as much as possible):

```
 <form action="" method="POST" 
       id="serviceForm" name="serviceForm">
 <label>Container Selected</label>
     *** js populates bolNum & containerNum and displays it in these inputs ***
 <input type="text" name="containerNum" id="containerNum" class="containerNum" />
 <input type="text" name="bolNum" id="bolNum" class="bolNum" />
     *** there are more form inputs, I just want to focus on the above 2 ***
 <input type="submit" id="modal-form-submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
 <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $bolArray = explode(',', $_POST['bolNum']);
       $containerArray = explode(',', $_POST['containerNum']);
       $count = count($bolArray);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
       $bolService = $bolArray[$i];
       $containerService = $containerArray[$i];

       *** here is the first query ***
       $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO serviceTable (bol, container) 
                    VALUES ('$bolService', '$containerService')";

       *** here is the second query ***
       $updateService = "UPDATE dispatchTable SET serviceColumn = 'Y' 
       WHERE CONTAINER_NUM = '$containerService' AND BOL_NUM = '$bolService'";
       $updateServiceQuery = @mysql_query($updateService) or die ('error');

       if(mysql_query($sqlQuery)){
          $success = true;
          }
       else{
          $success = false;
          }
        }
      }
       if($success){
         echo "saved";
         }
       else{
         echo "not saved";
         }
       ?>
 </form>
```

Here is another form. Basically, they are both the same, except for the names of the forms, and the names of the queries in the PHP.

```
 <form class="well-small" action="" method="POST" 
       id="storageForm" name="storageForm">
 <label>Container Selected</label>
     *** js populates bolNum & containerNum and displays it in these inputs ***
 <input type="text" name="containerNum" id="containerNum" class="containerNum" />
 <input type="text" name="bolNum" id="bolNum" class="bolNum" />
     *** there are more form inputs, I just want to focus on the above 2 ***
 <input type="submit" id="modal-form-submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
 <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $bolArray = explode(',', $_POST['bolNum']);
       $containerArray = explode(',', $_POST['containerNum']);
       $count = count($bolArray);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
       $bolStorage = $bolArray[$i];
       $containerStorage = $containerArray[$i];

       *** here is the first query ***
       $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO storageTable (bol, container) 
                    VALUES ('$bolStorage', '$containerStorage')";

       *** here is the second query ***
       $updateStorage = "UPDATE dispatchTable SET storageColumn = 'Y' 
       WHERE CONTAINER_NUM = '$containerStorage' AND BOL_NUM = '$bolStorage'";
       $updateStorageQuery = @mysql_query($updateStorage) or die ('error');

       if(mysql_query($sqlQuery)){
          $success = true;
          }
       else{
          $success = false;
          }
        }
      }
       if($success){
         echo "saved";
         }
       else{
         echo "not saved";
         }
       ?>
 </form>
```

If you'll notice the 2 queries per form, you will see the INSERT query updates to a different table.  Whereas both forms have an UPDATE query that updates the same table, only different columns.

Again, I am having no problem with the INSERT queries.  The problem lies with the UPDATE queries.  Basically, if you complete the serviceForm, it should update the column in dispatchTable called serviceColumn, which it does.  But it also updates the storageColumn which is also in dispatchTable.  Vice versa for the completion of the storageForm.

When a form is complete, it should ONLY update the specified column for that form, not both columns for both forms.

I am not sure if it has something to do with the action of the forms being blank. Although I do believe the action may be the key to getting this to work correctly. I am not sure where to start.

Please advise.

*** NOTE : I WILL BE USING PDO OR MYSQLI FOR THE NEXT APPLICATION ***

Comment: Why did I get a down vote?  Did I not word this cleary?  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename submit buttons in your forms:

```
....
<input type="submit" id="modal-form-submit" name="service_submit" value="Save" />
 <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['service_submit'])){
....
```

and

```
....
<input type="submit" id="modal-form-submit" name="storage_submit" value="Save" />
 <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['storage_submit'])){
....
```

Both fields are updated because both parts of PHP code are executed. The reason is you check the same post field `$_POST['submit']` that is set when you submit any form on your page.

**P.S.**

Try to change your queries to make one query instead a lot of queries in a loop. Your application will work faster.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Your code have one big hole named SQL injection. Try at least to escape values passed in query, even better use parameterized queries: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php